# Actionscript 3.0 Get all instances of a class?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript, for-loop, instance

I got a ton of movieclips in a class. Is there a more efficient way to apply a function to every instance in the class other than this?

```
var textArray:Array = [
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin1,
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin2,
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin3,
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin4,
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin5,
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin6,
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin7, 
    //... ... ...  
    interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin15
];                                     
for each (var interludeText:MovieClip in interludeBeginText)
{
   interludeText.alpha = 0 //clear all text first
}
```

Also for some reason this doesn't work:

```
interludes.interludeIntro.alpha = 0;
```

It permanently turns that class invisible, even if I try to make specific instances visible later with:

```
interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin1.alpha = 1;
```

I have NO idea why the above doesn't work. I want to turn every single instance in the class interludeIntro invisible, but I want to turn specific instances visible later.

(btw I have no idea how to insert code on this website, pressing "code" doesn't do anything, so pardon the bad formatting)

Comment: Take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help please.

Comment: the behavior of `interludes.interludeIntro.alpha = 0;` is expected, because all children have their alpha multiplied with their parents' alpha. So if you set a container's `alpha` to `0`, all children have an effective `alpha` of `0` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but what may be useful is that, in ActionScript you can refer to properties by name, like `myObject["someProperty"]`.

Using that, you can iterate over properties if they follow some naming scheme, so for example:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 15; i ++)
    interludes.interludeIntro["interludeBegin" + i].alpha = 0;
```

That iterates over `interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin1` through `...15` and sets their `alpha` properties to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

When you do that:

```
interludes.interludeIntro.alpha = 0;
```

you turn the movie clip **and** all its children invisible.

So later when you do that:

```
 interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin1.alpha = 1;
```

You make the movie clip visible, but since its parent is still invisible, you don't see anything. The solution is to loop through the movie clips and make each of them invisible/visible.

```
// Keep the parent visible at all time
interludes.interludeIntro.alpha = 1;

for (var i:int = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
    textArray[i].alpha = 0;
}

// Now this will work:
interludes.interludeIntro.interludeBegin1.alpha = 1;
```